# How to transform pyspark dataframe 1x9 to 3x3

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, transformation

Im using pyspark dataframe.
I have a df which is 1x9

example

```
temp = spark.read.option("sep","\n").csv("temp.txt")
```

temp :

> ```
> sam
> 11
> newyork
> john
> 13
> boston
> eric
> 22
> texas
> ```

without using **Pandas** library, How can I transform this to 3x3 dataframe with columns name,age,city ?

like this :

> name,age,city
>
> sam,11,newyork
>
> john,13,boston

Comment: it can be done, but it will not be efficient.

Comment: efficency is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read the file as an `rdd` to take advantage of `zipWithIndex` to add an index to your data.

```
rdd = sc.textFile("temp.txt")
```

We can now use truncating division to create an index with which to group records together. Use this new index as the `key` for the `rdd`. The corresponding `values` will be a tuple of the header, which can be computed using the modulus, and the actual value. (Note the index returned by `zipWithIndex` will be at the end of the record, which is why we use `row[1]` for the division/mod.)

Next use `reduceByKey` to `add` the value `tuple`s together. This will give you a tuple of keys and values (in sequence). Use `map` to turn that into a `Row` (to keep column headers, etc).

Finally use `toDF()` to convert to a DataFrame. You can use `select(header)` to get the columns in the desired order.

```
from operator import add
from pyspark.sql import Row

header = ["name", "age", "city"]

df = rdd.zipWithIndex()\
    .map(lambda row: (row[1]//3, (header[row[1]%3], row[0])))\
    .reduceByKey(add)\
    .map(lambda row: Row(**dict(zip(row[1][::2], row[1][1::2]))))\
    .toDF()\
    .select(header)

df.show()
#+----+---+-------+
#|name|age|   city|
#+----+---+-------+
#| sam| 11|newyork|
#|eric| 22|  texas|
#|john| 13| boston|
#+----+---+-------+
```